# Chrome extension that changes mouse icon when hovering over a link with _blank attribute

Tags: chrome, mouse, hyperlink

When I hover over a link with the mouse I would like to know if the link will open in a new tab (has a _blank html attribute).

Is there a Chrome extension that implements this?

Comment: Thanks! If it's going to be in the Chrome Web Store please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I've made an extension to do this.

You can install in from my [Github repo](https://github.com/shu8/changeCursorIconOnBlankAttribute) - just download the `.crx` file and drag it onto `chrome://extensions`.

You can change the cursor icon by going to `chrome://extensions`, finding this extension, clicking `Options` and choosing it from there

---

Alternatively, you can use this bookmarklet ([generated via Ben Alman's Jquery Bookmarklet Generator](http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/)):

```
javascript: (function (e, a, g, h, f, c, b, d) {
    if (!(f = e.jQuery) || g > f.fn.jquery || h(f)) {
        c = a.createElement("script");
        c.type = "text/javascript";
        c.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + g + "/jquery.min.js";
        c.onload = c.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (!b && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == "loaded" || d == "complete")) {
                h((f = e.jQuery).noConflict(1), b = 1);
                f(c).remove()
            }
        };
        a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)
    }
})(window, document, "1.3.2", function ($, L) {
    $('a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('target') == '_blank') {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'crosshair');
            }, function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

(change the `crosshair` to whichever cursor you prefer - you can see all the cursor's on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor).